# How to use routing and ng-view in AngularJS v1.3.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, ng-view

I'm trying to run [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/geb5fh1Ns4fZC5XDOvaV?p=preview) about routing, which uses `AngularJS v1.0.7`. But I want to make it work using `AngularJS v1.3.3`

Everything in my example works but the `ng-view` part. So I'm not sure whether the problem is the `ng-view` or the `routing` itself.

As [the tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/) suggests, I tried 3 ways of calling `ng-view`. But none seems to work.

> You can define ng-view in main html file in one of the below way.
>
> ```
> <div ng-view=""></div>
> <ng-view></ng-view>
> <div class="ng-view"></div>
> ```

How should I make it work in `AngularJS v1.3.3`?

Comment: you need to provide more of your code to let us help you. All those three options should work the same way so your problem is somewhere else..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of angular included routing in the core.

To use it now you have to include `angular-route.js` or `angular-route.min.js` also and inject `ngRoute` as a module dependency.

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

[Original example upgraded](http://plnkr.co/edit/YESd7bx3gqw8MfCSZp4i?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. it works fine now. Should I update my question to include the real problem?

Comment: No...Should be fine. That's what answers are for

Answer (score 2):

After angular 1.2 you need to depend your module on [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kbdzw0VTkg0xPykc0vLp?p=preview)

If you click on the error in your Dev Console, you'll see this at the middle of the page:

> In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own
>   module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x or
>   later, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.